# ASP.NET user activity page like Twitter

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net

I want to make a system where users can see the shares of the other user, like Twitter or Facebook Post System. But I couldn't do it. What I want to do is: I want to sort the wall posts of all other users that the user has followed so that the last maximum is 1 month. It's the same on Twitter. However, I can't list all other users posts by the order of the user.

I will be grateful if you could help me. Below is the final version of the code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["User"] == null)
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            Response.Redirect("/login?redirect=" + path + "");
        }
        else
        {
            Username = Session["User"].ToString();
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindRepeater();
        }

    }


   public int PageSize;
   private void BindRepeater()
   {
        using (var mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE Sender='"+ Username + "' ORDER by id DESC", mySqlConnection);

            MySqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

            var myData = new List<string>();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    String a1 = reader["Receiver"].ToString();
                    myData.Add(a1);

                    // this part is not active, set the active flag in sql to 0
                    using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection1 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
                    {

                        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
                        cmd1.Connection = mySqlConnection1;
                        MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                        cmd1.CommandText = "Select * from profile WHERE (username=@0 AND time < Now() and time > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 1 WEEK)) ORDER by id DESC";
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", a1);

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        ad.SelectCommand = cmd1;
                        ad.Fill(dt);

                        PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
                        pgitems.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                        pgitems.AllowPaging = true;

                        //Control page size from here
                        PageSize = 15;
                        pgitems.PageSize = PageSize;
                        pgitems.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber;
                        if (pgitems.PageCount > 1)
                        {
                            rptPaging.Visible = true;
                            ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
                            for (int i = 0; i <= pgitems.PageCount - 1; i++)
                            {
                                pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
                            }
                            rptPaging.DataSource = pages;
                            rptPaging.DataBind();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rptPaging.Visible = false;
                        }

                        RepCourse.DataSource = pgitems;
                        RepCourse.DataBind();

                        if (RepCourse.Items.Count == 0)
                        {
                            emptyact.Visible = true;
                        }

                        mySqlConnection1.Close();
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("No Data Found.");
            }

            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
        BindRepeater();
    }
```

Comment: The way that you are setting `pgitems` and binding it inside of your `while` loop, doesn't seem workable.  usually this will only bind on the last loop iteration.  Please tell us what is it currently doing wrong.  What are you seeing?

Comment: @tgolisch Actually, I think this code is all wrong for me. I would like to have the share (wall post etc.) that the person followed by the users to be listed again as if they were old. However, this code lists the followers as a list. That is, the user who is followed first is selected, then all the share of that user in the last 1 week are listed, then the other user is passed on. However, as the same on Twitter, I want to sort by date, users of shares that are being followed. I hope that I can tell you what I want to do. Thank you for your help.